# How to get ggpubr make figure title partly bold?

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, r-markdown, ggpubr

Hi I'm using the package `ggpubr` to create publishable figures in R, and I'm struggling with getting my title partly bold (I'm trying to format my figure in AMA format style). I'm working in R markdown, `ggplot` and LaTeX. to create my files. I only need "Figure 1." to be in boldface. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. My code:

```
ggpubr::annotate_figure(PLOT,
            top = ggpubr::text_grob("Figure 1. Rest of the title NOT IN BOLD FONT FACE",
                                    face = "bold", 
                                    size = 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try

**font.main, font.submain, font.caption, font.x, font.y**
a vector of length 3 indicating respectively the size (e.g.: 14), the style (e.g.: "plain", "bold", "italic", "bold.italic") and the color (e.g.: "red") of main title, subtitle, caption, xlab and ylab, respectively. For example font.x = c(14, "bold", "red").

Cheers.

Comment: No I didn't try and don't know where to add it exactly, also I only want the the "Figure 1." to be bold. In my table titles with `kable()` and LaTeX I use `caption =  "\\textbf{Table 1.} Rest of Title"` with `escape = FALSE` . No solution like that in `ggpubr` ?